# How can i create a persistent data chart with Flask and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to add a real-time chart to my Flask webapp. This chart, other than current updated data, should contain historical data too.

At the moment i can create the chart and i can make it real time but i have no idea how to make the data 'persistent', so i can't see what the chart looked like days or weeks ago.

I'm using a Javascript charting library, while Data is being sent from my Flask script, but what it's not really clear is how i can "store" my data on Javascript. At the moment, indeed, the chart will reset each time the page is loaded.

How would it be possible to accomplish that? Is there an example for it?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Normally you'd use a database for something like this, store the data in the database with your flask app, and read it back from your app each time data was sent to the client. There are other methods that might work for you (e.g. using localstorage) but without knowing more about your use case its hard to advise.

Comment: Well, i'll be sending a lot of data every minute, so my dataset will become big eventually, i will be charting trading data

Comment: Yep, database. Saying anything else here is probably grounds for a holy war (but I like postgresql and psycopg2...)

Comment: What it's not really clear to me it's how the records from my DB will be stored on a frontend JS, i don't think it's possible to query a db on a frontend, is it?

Comment: They won't be stored on the frontend. They'll be loaded each time you hit the page. You can use a single page app, and localStorage, techniques like that, to cache data (i.e. improve load times if they visited recently, or leave the page running). But you need to be able to restore all the data (from the database) if the user changes browsers, or reinstalls their computer, or whatever. The database is the authoritative source.

Comment: Client is also capable to store big amount of data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the data in a database and or in a file and extract from there .

You can also try to use dash or you can make on the right side a menu with dates like 21 september and see the chart from that day .

For dash you can look on YouTube at Sentdex